# Javascript Object.values

Tags: object

I have an object with years and it's values

```
const years = {};
rows.forEach(row => {
  const cols = row.split(';');
  years[cols[0]] += cols[3];
});
```

This part works fine.

I want to exctracts the values. I tried this:

```
Object.values(years),
```

But it doesn't work. Maybe the values are not set correct.

Comment: please add an example of `data` and the wanted result.

Comment: So, what *do* you get?

Comment: btw, misuse of an array instead of an object, no init value of an element. just adding a value returns `undefined2`, where undefined is the value of the item and the number is your string of splitting a row. you need `years = {}` and later `years[cols[0]] += (years[cols[0]] || 0) + +cols[3];`

Comment: You'll probably want to initialise `years` as an *object*, not an array…?

Comment: Can you do a ```console.log(years)``` after the forEach loop and add the result.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Basically you need an object

```
years = {}
```

and later with a default value for not initialised value and a numerical value for adding.

```
years[cols[0]] = (years[cols[0]] || 0) + +cols[3];
```

```js
const
    data = 'xyz\n2006;7;1;20;0\n2006;8;1;40;1\n2007;1;1;30;0\n2007;6;1;60;0',
    years = {},
    rows = data.split('\n').slice(1); //It's simple csv text file

rows.forEach(row => {
    const cols = row.split(';');
    years[cols[0]] = (years[cols[0]] || 0) + +cols[3];
});

console.log(Object.keys(years));
console.log(Object.values(years));
```

Comment: Yeah i missed the object initalizer. It returns 2007: NaN how can i solve it?

Comment: you need `=` instead of `+=`.

Answer (score 0):

When you do

```
years[cols[0]] += cols[3];
```

if years[cols[0]] has not been initialized before, the value will be undefined. If you add number to undefined it will be NaN.

initialize like this:

```
if (!years[cols[0]]) years[cols[0]] = 0;
```